# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rubymine

I am trying to run `users_test.rb` file which just has

```
test "the truth" do
     assert true
   end
```

I do have a likes table, still I am getting this error. Why so?

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
➜  channelappnew  rake db:test:clone
➜  channelappnew  rake db:test:clone_structure
➜  channelappnew  rake db:migrate
➜  channelappnew  rake db:test:load
➜  channelappnew  rake db:test:prepare
➜  channelappnew  rake db:test:purge
➜  channelappnew  ruby -Itest test/unit/user_test.rb
Loaded suite test/unit/user_test
Started
E

Error:
test_the_truth(UserTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'likes'




Finished in 0.058371 seconds.

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

17.13 tests/s, 0.00 assertions/s
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

before test do `rake db:test:prepare`

Answer (score 5):

Have you run `rake db:migrate`?
Check database if the table exists. If you are working with sqlite, then call `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3` and then issue command `.schema`
You can manually delete database `db/test.sqlite3` and then re-create it with `rake db:setup`.

Comment: I have this in my database.yml `test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.
  database: ":memory:"
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000`

Comment: It showed me this : `➜  channelappnew  rake db:migrate                   
➜  channelappnew  rake db:setup
db/development.sqlite3 already exists
-- create_table("likes", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0379s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0165s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0003s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20110929162245,
➜  channelappnew  ruby -Itest test/unit/user_test.rb
Loaded suite test/unit/user_test
Error:
test_the_truth(UserTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'likes'`

Comment: It doesn't matter what you have in database.yml yet. You obviously are referring to a table that does not exist. Tables are created by migrations. Check db/migrations folder and see if you have code that ever creates the 'likes' table.

Comment: I modified `database: db/test.` to `database: db/test.sqlite3`, but still same error.

Comment: Paste your fixtures for that table. Maybe those help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3946/discussion-between-zilupe-and-vinisa)

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your fixtures? It has happened to me that I modified a migration but the fixture staid the same, therefore causing a error.

Comment: Yes I did check for all the possible problems that people had. My fixtures seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is caused due to multiple versions of active record gems. Please uninstall all gems except one that your application is using. I faced the same problem and did same what i said. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and found the solution in db/schema.rb:

```
# Could not dump table "xxx" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'bool' for column 'yyy'
```

maybe this helps!

"bool" worked everywhere except for this schema.rb, but the migrations where executed correctly in development mode.